# Javascript Code Words Only After Second Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I'm trying to use an accordion menu in my webpage. It's supposed to show only one panel at a time when clicked, and js code must be called with an onclick function. All works fine when I add js code between script tags in html, but I need to use onclick and call the script from external .js file instead. However when I do it, code stars working only after second click. How to solve it? (no jquery)

**NOTE:** JS file must be called in `<head>` section in html.

HTML:

```
<button class="course-accordion" onclick="openaccordion()">Title 1</button>
<div class="course-panel">Text 1</div>
<button class="course-accordion" onclick="openaccordion()">Title 2</button>
<div class="course-panel">Text 2</div>
<button class="course-accordion" onclick="openaccordion()">Title 3</button>
<div class="course-panel">Text 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
button.course-accordion {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    line-height: 1.5em;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: 0px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
}
/*When the button is active or mouse hovers*/
button.course-accordion.active, button.course-accordion:hover {
    background-color: rgba(166,166,166,0.6);
}
/*button not active*/
button.course-accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
/* minus button */
button.course-accordion.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}
div.course-panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: transparent;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    width: 96%;
    font-family: "Raleway";
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    letter-spacing: .4px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,.88);
}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    function openaccordion() {
        //this is the button
        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            //when one of the buttons are clicked run this function
          acc[i].onclick = function() {
            //variables
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
            var coursePanel = document.getElementsByClassName("course-panel");
            var courseAccordion = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion");
            var courseAccordionActive = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion active");

            /*if pannel is already open - minimize*/
            if (panel.style.maxHeight){
                //minifies current pannel if already open
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                //removes the 'active' class as toggle didnt work on browsers minus chrome
                this.classList.remove("active");
            } else { //pannel isnt open...
                //goes through the buttons and removes the 'active' css (+ and -)
                for (var ii = 0; ii < courseAccordionActive.length; ii++) {
                    courseAccordionActive[ii].classList.remove("active");
                }
                //Goes through and removes 'activ' from the css, also minifies any 'panels' that might be open
                for (var iii = 0; iii < coursePanel.length; iii++) {
                  this.classList.remove("active");
                  coursePanel[iii].style.maxHeight = null;
                }
              //opens the specified pannel
              panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
              //adds the 'active' addition to the css.
              this.classList.add("active");
            } 
          }//closing to the acc onclick function
        }//closing to the for loop.
    }
```

Comment: That's because you are only adding the click handlers that provide the actual accordion functionality, _inside_ of your `openaccordion` function. That makes little sense to begin with.

Comment: can you show us only that part, which makes that? its really hard to start reading the whole code

Comment: Each click on a button adds three click handlers to the buttons. Click handlers are usually added when a page loads, once.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I forgot to mention an important detail: JS file must be called in <head> section in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `onclick` event, call the function on load itself.

You are calling `openaccordion` function on click of each button. The `openaccordion` is registering the `onclick` event of each button. When the button is clicked for the first time you are looping through the uttons and registering the onclick event for all the three buttons. Now the required action is registered but only after clicking the button for the first time. From next time onwards the button will behave as expected, that is because of the `onclick` listner written inside `openaccordion` function. But again when you click ay one of the button, the click event for each button will be regitered again. This is not needed.

Actually your `openaccordion` function is registring the click event for the three button. This need not to be called ach time when the button is clicked, insted only once when the document is loaded.

**Working fiddle**: I have updated the function name `openaccordion` to `registeraccordionEvents` since that is a more generic name for the functionality.

```js
function registeraccordionEvents() {
  //this is the button
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    //when one of the buttons are clicked run this function
    acc[i].onclick = function () {
      //variables
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      var coursePanel = document.getElementsByClassName("course-panel");
      var courseAccordion = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion");
      var courseAccordionActive = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion active");

      /*if pannel is already open - minimize*/
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        //minifies current pannel if already open
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        //removes the 'active' class as toggle didnt work on browsers minus chrome
        this.classList.remove("active");
      } else { //pannel isnt open...
        //goes through the buttons and removes the 'active' css (+ and -)
        for (var ii = 0; ii < courseAccordionActive.length; ii++) {
          courseAccordionActive[ii].classList.remove("active");
        }
        //Goes through and removes 'activ' from the css, also minifies any 'panels' that might be open
        for (var iii = 0; iii < coursePanel.length; iii++) {
          this.classList.remove("active");
          coursePanel[iii].style.maxHeight = null;
        }
        //opens the specified pannel
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        //adds the 'active' addition to the css.
        this.classList.add("active");
      }
    }//closing to the acc onclick function
  }//closing to the for loop.
}
registeraccordionEvents();
```

```css
button.course-accordion {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}

/*When the button is active or mouse hovers*/
button.course-accordion.active,
button.course-accordion:hover {
  background-color: rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.6);
}

/*button not active*/
button.course-accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/* minus button */
button.course-accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.course-panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: transparent;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 96%;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .88);
}
```

```html
<button class="course-accordion">Title 1</button>
<div class="course-panel">Text 1</div>
<button class="course-accordion">Title 2</button>
<div class="course-panel">Text 2</div>
<button class="course-accordion">Title 3</button>
<div class="course-panel">Text 3</div>
```

**Including the `script` in `head` section**

In the above example, the stackoverflow fiddle adds the script below the body section. But if you add the same script in the head section which is above the body, the app wont work. **WHY?** Because inside the function, we are accessing your `course-accordion` using `document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion")`. The `head` section gets invoked before the body is loaded. This makes the selector to return a list having length 0. Because at the time of script execution, there will not be no such element in the DOM, since the body wll be loaded after the script when we add script at the top of body. To avoid this, the function call `registeraccordionEvents` can be moved to body onload event of body. At this time the DOM elements wll be available.

**Working Fiddle**

```css
button.course-accordion {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  line-height: 1.5em;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
}

/*When the button is active or mouse hovers*/
button.course-accordion.active,
button.course-accordion:hover {
  background-color: rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.6);
}

/*button not active*/
button.course-accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/* minus button */
button.course-accordion.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

div.course-panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: transparent;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  width: 96%;
  font-family: "Raleway";
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  letter-spacing: .4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .88);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
    function registeraccordionEvents() {
      //this is the button
      var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        //when one of the buttons are clicked run this function
        acc[i].onclick = function () {
          //variables
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          var coursePanel = document.getElementsByClassName("course-panel");
          var courseAccordion = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion");
          var courseAccordionActive = document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion active");

          /*if pannel is already open - minimize*/
          if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            //minifies current pannel if already open
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            //removes the 'active' class as toggle didnt work on browsers minus chrome
            this.classList.remove("active");
          } else { //pannel isnt open...
            //goes through the buttons and removes the 'active' css (+ and -)
            for (var ii = 0; ii < courseAccordionActive.length; ii++) {
              courseAccordionActive[ii].classList.remove("active");
            }
            //Goes through and removes 'activ' from the css, also minifies any 'panels' that might be open
            for (var iii = 0; iii < coursePanel.length; iii++) {
              this.classList.remove("active");
              coursePanel[iii].style.maxHeight = null;
            }
            //opens the specified pannel
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            //adds the 'active' addition to the css.
            this.classList.add("active");
          }
        }//closing to the acc onclick function
      }//closing to the for loop.
    }
    // registeraccordionEvents();
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="registeraccordionEvents()">
  <button class="course-accordion">Title 1</button>
  <div class="course-panel">Text 1</div>
  <button class="course-accordion">Title 2</button>
  <div class="course-panel">Text 2</div>
  <button class="course-accordion">Title 3</button>
  <div class="course-panel">Text 3</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This script can be moved to an external file aswell. Please make sure that the function `registeraccordionEvents` is called during `body` `onload`. This time your selector `document.getElementsByClassName("course-accordion")` will return 3 nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your code works fine when I call JS file after the buttons in html. However I forgot to mention that JS file must be called in <head> section in html. Do you maybe know how to do it?

Comment: Javascript can be included anywhere inside an html. It can be done in multiple wats aswell. Refer https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_whereto.asp

Comment: If you want to include that in head part of your html, your html file should be like below <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script>
    alert("Insert the script here");
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  Insert the template here
</body>
</html>

Comment: Thank you, my html looks exactly like that. Actually I need to save that javascript code in a .js file, and call this file in <head> section in html, such as <head><script src="accordion.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: @tez you can do it in same way. Save in a separate file and add <script src="accordion.js" > in your head

Comment: I see, but it doesn't work. I just created an empty project with your codes, wrote your html meta tags you just wrote, and added <script src="accordion.js" along with css style file in the <head> tag as usual, but accordion doesn't function

Comment: @tez updated the answer with details, please see the answer.

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out now. In the <head> section I called the js file where I stored the function, and under the buttons in html I used <script>window.onload=registeraccordionEvents()</script>. Works fine at the moment. Thanks again

Comment: @tez you are welcome, please approve the answer if this is what you are looking for, happy to have an upvote aswell.